# how to install filemanager actions in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nautilus, 22.04

I am recently running on Ubuntu 22.04. And I wanted to install nautilus actions on my machine. When I looked for help, I came to know that the nautilus-actions app was the filemanager-actions app for Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried running `sudo apt install filemanager-actions` but it showed that

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package filemanager-actions
```

Please feel free to ask for other necessary information. Please do bear with me as I am very new to ubuntu and this forum.

Thank you very much.

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate what it is you are striving to achieve and what steps you took. As it stands, your question makes very little sense,

Comment: Did you install the `nautilus-actions` package? This is a transitional package and has both `filemanager-actions` and `nautilus-extension-fma` as a dependency. Also, please explain what didn't work. Did it not install or does it not do what it's supposed to do. If the later, please explain what it is supposed to do. Thanks.

Comment: No i didn't install the Nautilus actions package. How do I do it

Answer (score 5):

I found the project archived.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/filemanager-actions

The decision is made through the following two issues.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/Infrastructure/damned-lies/-/issues/255
https://gitlab.gnome.org/Infrastructure/Infrastructure/-/issues/671

This is why Ubuntu 22.04 does not have this package, because the upstream Gnome gave up this project.

Comment: So isn't there any way to add items to my right-click menu? I do know that I can do this by adding scripts but I am looking for better ways to do it.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any alternatives to filemanager-actions? I need to be able to right-click and access a terminal inside a directory.

Comment: OK; It is no more in the packages. A pity ! So witch way to install it from gitlab ?

Answer (score 3):

I've written a full-function replacement for this extension that works with the current version of Gnome Files:

https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus